# how to transfer pdf, mp3 or mp4 files using socket?

Tags: c, sockets, ipc

i have made one client server application in which client sends file (i.e ODT,PDF,MP3,MP4, etc) and server receives file.

i am dividing file in chunks and then transmits them in while loop.
below i have given main logic for both client and server.

when i do loop-back with 127.0.0.1, this code works successfully.

but when i runs client and server on two different PC, after transmitting a file client exits but server keeps receiving and then i have to press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>^<kbd>C</kbd>. the size of file at server side reaches over 1GB even if file size at client side is only around 4.2 MB.

and in loopback i am not getting such problem.

please tell me the needed corrections.

client.c

```
#define SIZE 512   // or anything else
char sendbuff[SIZE];
FILE *fr;
fr = fopen("1.mp3","r");
while(!feof(fr)){
    count = fread(sendbuff, SIZE,1,fr);
    count = send(clientsd, sendbuff,SIZE,0);  //clientsd is socket descriptor. 
}
send(clientsd, "xyz", 3, 0);      //sending '1'. tells server, transmission is over now. 
close(fr);
```

server.c

```
#define SIZE 512   // same as client side
char recvbuff[SIZE];

FILE *fw;
fw = fopen("2.mp3","w");
while(1){
    count = recv(connsd, recvbuff, SIZE,0);

    if(!strcmp(recvbuff,"xyz"))
    break;

    fwrite(recvbuff,SIZE, 1, fw);
    memset(recvbuff,0,SIZE);
}
printf("Exit while\n");
fclose(fw);
```

any other simple and efficient way to do this ?

NOTE : I have changed my question. here some answers are on my old question where i have transmitted "1" instead of "xyz". which was an error.

Comment: `if(recvbuff[0]=='1') break;` ... what?  Why?

Comment: @indiv Presume due to server calling `send(clientsd, "1", 1, 0);` to terminate the transfer.  Seems a poor way to check for the end of a file though.

Comment: client sends 1 to server to tell him that now i will not transmit any more data so this indicates end of transmission. if we removes it, than it will be infinite loop

Comment: @AeroX  before this i have tried send(clientsd,"quit",4,0); and at server side -> if(!strcmp(recvbuff,"quit")) break; 
but still having same problem.

Comment: And what happens if the file you are sending just happens to have the byte `0x31` there?  You don't need to tell the client that you're done anyway.  Just close the socket.  Or send the length of the file *first* so the receiver knows how many bytes to expect.  Also, it doesn't make sense to `count = recv(...)` and then completely ignore `count` and write `SIZE` bytes into the file.  Maybe you want to do something with `count` values that you're saving on the sender and receiver side instead of ignore them?

Comment: Because it's a UDP socket and you're losing packets on the network?  I can only guess based on the code you've shown.  Regardless, you have to fix the problems already pointed out whether or not they're the immediate cause of your problem because they're real bugs.

Comment: ok. but it is TCP socket.

Comment: @indiv one problem is solved . so now i am sending "xyz" instead of "1". thanks

Comment: Add code to check the return value of `send` and `recv`. If the return value is less than zero, call `perror` so you know what the error is.

Answer (score 1):

The most obvious problem is your stop condition on the server side.

You assume that if the first byte received is `'1'` (0x31) than the transfer is over, but it might be a byte of the data (if the first byte of the chunk in the file is actually `'1'`). So you need some other way to signal the end of the file. One possibility is to use a wrapping for each packet sent, for example, before each packet send a specific value (for example '1') followed by the length, and when the transfer is complete send '0' to signal that the transfer is completed.

The other problems I can see are that:

1. You open the files as read text ("r") and write text ("w") which will stop processing if the EOF sequence appears in the middle of the file, instead you need to open them as read/write **binary** ("rb" / "wb" respectively).
2. You use chunks of 512 bytes, what if the file is not a multiple of 512 bytes?